# How to read raw bytes of "/dev/rdisk" on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, filesystems, kernel-extension

From Mojave, open("/dev/rdisk0", O_RDONLY) will fail, becasue the System Integrity Protection.
Now I am trying to build a kernel extension for accessing rdisk0.
How to implement the equivalent user space C API(open/read)?
Or is there other way can access raw bytes of /dev/rdisk0?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do the raw access to disk since Mojave (or maybe even from High Sierra, don't remember) in usermode.

You will need to utilize the vnode_open and vn_rdwr functions from vnode.h

There are some comments there, they should help you with placing correct parameters.